# Jasmine testing, .not.toHaveBeenCalled();

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, code-coverage, istanbul

I am doing unit testing with Jasmine, and Instanbul. I am testing a submit form. And I have already several unit tests for it. But now I want that if:

```
this.allowSubmitAgain = false; this method:

this.diplomaService.saveDiplomaMetaData(false, this.resources.opslaanSpinnerTekst).pipe(map(() => {
```

not will be executed. Because on this line in instanbul:

```
if (this.allowSubmitAgain) {
```

it says E: else path not taken.

This is the whole method:

```
diplomaDataSubmitted() {
        if (this.formModel && this.formModel.form.valid) {

            this.formService.formStoreService.hideValidationSummary(this.formName);
            Eif (this.allowSubmitAgain) {
                this.allowSubmitAgain = false;
                this.diplomaService.saveDiplomaMetaData(false, this.resources.opslaanSpinnerTekst).pipe(map(() => {
                    const documents: DocumentModel[] = this.formModel.getAngularFormControl(DiplomaFormKeysModel.keys.diplomasUpload).value.files;

                    this.diplomaService.saveDocumentForDiploma(documents, () => {
                        this.router.navigateByUrl(RoutesRegisterModel.pathnameMyRegisterRouteDiplomas).then(() => {
                            this.feedbackService.addSuccessMessageOnMainPortal(
                                {
                                    key: this.resourceKeys.succesvolWijziging,
                                    value: this.resources.succesvolWijziging,
                                }
                            );
                        });
                    }, (error: any) => {
                        this.allowSubmitAgain = true;
                        observableThrowError(error);
                    }, this.resources, this.resourceKeys);
                })).subscribe(() => { }, (error: any) => {
                    this.allowSubmitAgain = true;
                    observableThrowError(error);
                });
            }
        } else {
            this.formService.formStoreService.showValidationSummary(this.formName);

        }
    }
```

And this is my unit test:

```
it('should not allow submit beaucse form has errors', fakeAsync(() => {

        // Arrange
        const spySaveMetaDataDiploma = spyOn(diplomaServiceMock, 'saveDiplomaMetaData');

        diplomaServiceMock.returnErrorResponse();
        // Act
        component.diplomaDataSubmitted();
        fixture.detectChanges();

        // Assert
         expect(spySaveMetaDataDiploma).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
        console.log('testcase');
        expect(component.allowSubmitAgain).toBe(false);


    }));
```

But I get this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined.
```

So how to fix that?

Thank you

I have it now like this:

```
it('should not allow submit beaucse form has errors', fakeAsync(() => {

        // Arrange

        const spySaveDiploma = spyOn(diplomaServiceMock, 'saveDiplomaMetaData').and.callThrough();

        // Act
        component.allowSubmitAgain = false;

        // Assert

        console.log('testcase');
        expect(component.allowSubmitAgain).toBe(false);
        expect(spySaveDiploma).not.toHaveBeenCalled();

    }));
```

And I don't get errors.

But in the code coverage of Istanbul. The 'else path not taken' is still visible.

Eif (this.allowSubmitAgain) {

So on this line it still says else path not taken.

if I do it like this:

```
 it('should not allow submit again beaucse form has errors', fakeAsync(() => {

        const spySaveDiploma = spyOn(diplomaServiceMock, 'saveDiplomaMetaData').and.callThrough();

        component.diplomaDataSubmitted();
        component.allowSubmitAgain = false;
        fixture.detectChanges();

        console.log('testcase');
        expect(component.allowSubmitAgain).toBe(false);
        expect(spySaveDiploma).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    }));
```

I get this error:

```
Expected spy saveDiplomaMetaData not to have been called.
```

But what I have to do ?

Comment: Could you try eliminating this error by adding `Observable` to the `spyOn(diplomaServiceMock, 'saveDiplomaMetaData')` first? So we can assert what's wrong with the test cases.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I updated the post.

Comment: There is no action in your newly updated test case. Could you update it and share us the test case result?

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: I updated the post with the code coverage

Comment: The test case you have just updated (after `I have it now like this:`) does not include any actions like: `component.diplomaDataSubmitted(); fixture.detectChanges();` in the first case.


----

The error that you've got before (`subscribe`) indicated that the unit under test did call the line `this.diplomaService.saveDiplomaMetaData`. That was why I wanted to see how the assert parts would report after adding correct `Observable` return.

Comment: I updated the post. But what I have to do?

Comment: The test case failed because `saveDiplomaMetaData` is called, but it shouldn't, right? Then let try to arrange it by adding `component.allowSubmitAgain = false;` before any actions.

Comment: Yes that was the case! Thank you

Comment: So solved! Thank you. ok

Comment: You're welcome :)